# Model not found: product.product

Tags: odoo-8

I am new in Odoo development. I want to add product brand and country for the products. I just created the form view and menu for the brand under product menu in warehouse. Now I want to add a field for the brand in product view. I am trying to extend the product.product model for it but the model not found error occurs. I have no idea what is happening.

Error details:

```
2016-03-09 09:18:15,609 2562 INFO hat_dev openerp.modules.loading: 

loading 1 modules...
2016-03-09 09:18:15,620 2562 INFO hat_dev openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2016-03-09 09:18:15,648 2562 INFO hat_dev openerp.modules.loading: loading 55 modules...
2016-03-09 09:18:15,807 2562 INFO hat_dev openerp.modules.module: module openautoparts_erp: creating or updating database tables
2016-03-09 09:18:15,838 2562 INFO hat_dev openerp.modules.loading: loading openautoparts_erp/product_brand/product_brand_views.xml
2016-03-09 09:18:15,893 2562 INFO hat_dev openerp.modules.loading: loading openautoparts_erp/product_brand/partner.xml
2016-03-09 09:18:15,919 2562 ERROR hat_dev openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_ui_view: Model not found: product.product

Error context:
View `partner.brand`
[view_id: 2112, xml_id: n/a, model: product.product, parent_id: 262]
2016-03-09 09:18:15,926 2562 INFO hat_dev werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2016 09:18:15] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2016-03-09 09:18:15,952 2562 ERROR hat_dev werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 290, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1290, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1428, in dispatch
    ir_http = request.registry['ir.http']
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 346, in registry
    return openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(self.db) if self.db else None
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 339, in get
    update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 351, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 901, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 987, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 853, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n, mode=mode)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 763, in _tag_record
    id = self.pool['ir.model.data']._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1064, in _update
    res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 255, in create
    context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 372, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4094, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 508, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4285, in _create
    recs._validate_fields(vals)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 1272, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError('\n'.join(errors))
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition
```

Error details:
Model not found: product.product

```
Error context:
View `partner.brand`
[view_id: 2112, xml_id: n/a, model: product.product, parent_id: 262]" while parsing /opt/odoo/custom/openautoparts_erp/product_brand/partner.xml:5, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_brand_form_view">
        <field name="name">partner.brand</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <notebook position="inside">
                <page string="Brands">
                    <group>
                        <field name="brand"/>
                        <field name="brand_ids"/>
                    </group>
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </field>
    </record>
```

My model is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



from openerp import fields, models

class Product(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    # Add a new column to the product.product model
    brand = fields.Char("brand", required=True)

    brand_ids = fields.One2many(
        'product.brand', string='Brand Name', readonly=True)
```

And my view file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<openerp>
    <data>
         <!-- Add brand field to existing view  -->
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_brand_form_view">
            <field name="name">partner.brand</field>
            <field name="model">product.product</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <notebook position="inside">
                    <page string="Brands">
                        <group>
                            <field name="brand"/>
                            <field name="brand_ids"/>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Did you import the `python file`.

Comment: Does your module depend on "product"? (In the __openerp__.py file)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I forget to add the dependency in openerp.

Answer (score 0):

Check Your dependency in  **__openerp__.py** file and add ***"depends" : ["product"]*** module if not added like this.

```
{
    "name" : "product_brand",
    "version" : "1.1",
    "author" : "Open",
    "category" : "Product Brands",
    "depends" : ["base", "product"],
    "installable": True,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class is not configured properly

```
brand_ids = fields.One2many('product.brand', string='Brand Name', readonly=True)
```

It should be this:

```
brand_ids = fields.One2many('product.brand', 'product_id', string='Brand Name', readonly=True)
```